# Python , how to convert this iterations into for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

this are the iterations

```
i = 0

s_array[i].append(f_array[i][i])
s_array[i].append(f_array[i+1][i])
s_array[i].append(f_array[i+2][i])

s_array[i+1].append(f_array[i][i+1])
s_array[i+1].append(f_array[i+1][i+1])

s_array[i+2].append(f_array[i][i+2])
```

I want to convert this iterations into for loop
for example like this

```
for i in range(something):
        for j in range(something):
                s_array[i].append(f_array[j][i])
```

I tried many trial and errors, but didn't got any solution

Comment: Why? Additionally it is unclear according to what rules the different index offsets are to be calculated.

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: I don't think "iterations" means what you think it means.

Comment: basically i want to This is my first array
```
f_array = [['a', 'ab', 'abc'], ['b', 'bc'], ['c']]```
I want to convert this f_array into this s_array
```
s_array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['ab', 'bc'], ['abc']] ``` @Scott Hunter

Comment: So i tried above code and i got solution, but I want to put that code in for loop means I want to make it dynamic @Chris Doyle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent iterations:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3 - i):
        s_array[i].append(f_array[j][i])
```

For example:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3 - i):
        print(i,"-->", j, i)
    print("")
```

Output:

```
0 --> 0 0
0 --> 1 0
0 --> 2 0
1 --> 0 1
1 --> 1 1
2 --> 0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to append values to an array using loops, you could try nested for loops as you have indicated. Also, since you are appending fewer values as the iterations continue, you could implement a negative step value for one of the range() functions in the loops so that you iterate fewer times.

Try doing something like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3-i):
        s_array[i].append(f_array[j][i])
```

Hopefully, this should solve your problem.